# :nth-of-type(N) doesn't work in behat+mink+selenium2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I am using `Behat+Mink+Selenium2` to find an element using CSS selectors using `tr.product:nth-of-type(N)`

```
$row=$page->find('css',sprintf('tr.product:nth-of-type("%d")', $i));
```

I have also tried

```
$row=$page->find('css', sprintf('tr[class=product]:nth-of-type("%d")', $i));
```

but none of them work. Is there any other alternative to selecting every nth row with a class of product?

Comment: :nth-child doesn't work too!

Comment: which browser are you controlling selenium with?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/Behat/Mink/issues/268).  I managed to get around it by changing my browser from Firefox to PhantomJS.

behat.yml:

```
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            default_session: selenium2
            browser_name: phantomjs
```